# R markdown + bookdown + word output: how to place figure caption on top of figure

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, bookdown

I am struggling with something simple: I want to generate a word document with a figure and add the figure caption on top (instead of at the bottom of the figure).
Please have a look at example at the end of the post where the caption is at the bottom of the plot.
I found several examples solving my problem, but they are with latex and pdf output.
Any help is appreciated and I suspect this must be a one-liner.

Cheers

````
---
output: 
  bookdown::word_document2:
  fig_caption: yes
---

```{r, mydoc ,  echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE}


options(tidyverse.quiet = TRUE)


options(message = FALSE)


library(tidyverse, warn.conflicts = FALSE)


df<-tibble(x=seq(20), y=seq(20))


```{r spending, echo=FALSE,fig.cap="My caption bla bla.",fig.height = 6, fig.width = 12}

ggplot(data = df, aes(x  = x, y=y)) +
    geom_line()

``
````

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/word-officedown.html, you can use {officedown} like:

```
---
output:  
  officedown::rdocx_document: 
    plots:
      topcaption: true
---
```

```
options(tidyverse.quiet = TRUE)
options(message = FALSE)
library(tidyverse, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(officedown)
df<-tibble(x=seq(20), y=seq(20))
```

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x  = x, y=y)) +
  geom_line()
```

which produces something like:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is also something I had briefly explored. But the ensuing document for some reason does not number the figures.

Comment: Ah, I see. Don't have word on hand, but what about preparing a word template with proper figure + caption location and using it like `reference_docx: "template.docx"`? I was using template some time ago at company, but never to such extend to relocate captions..

Comment: Hi! This would go overboard. I have already a word text with many plots and tables and references which work. I just need (company policy) to have the figure captions on the top. I am OK with an officedown solution, but it destroys table and figure numbering and I try to understand if it is a bug in the package.